# threejs texture causes "GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements"

Tags: dictionary, three.js, webgl, textures

I'm trying to apply a texture to a geometry created at runtime, reading a binary asset from a remote server.
I create the geometry assigning UVs (geometry.faceVertexUvs = uvs;), normals (face.vertexNormals.push(...)) and tangents (face.vertexTangents.push(...)).

If I try to create a mesh with a basic material, there are no problems, but when I create the mesh with that geometry and I try to apply my texture, webgl doesn't display any geometry and I get this warning:

[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1

Does anybody know what is going on? I think that my geometry has something wrong, because if I use a THREE.Sphere, I can actually apply the texture.

But everyone told me that in order to apply texture I need UVs, and I have'em.

I think that my faceVertexUvs is wrong.

The real question is: geometry.faceVertexUvs.length should be equal to geometry.vertices.length, or it should be equal to geometry.faces.length ?

Thank you very much.

PS: I've already read the following posts

[WebGL drawElements out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751791/webgl-drawelements-out-of-range)

[Three JS Map Material causes WebGL Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531759/three-js-map-material-causes-webgl-warning)

[THREEjs can't use the material on the JSON Model when initializing. Gives me WebGL errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196516/threejs-cant-use-the-material-on-the-json-model-when-initializing-gives-me-web)

[Loading a texture for a custom geometry causes “GL_INVALID_OPERATION” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239627/loading-a-texture-for-a-custom-geometry-causes-gl-invalid-operation-error)

Comment: in general every vertex needs a (u,v)-vector so  "geometry.faceVertexUvs.length should be equal to geometry.vertices.length" Maybe you can give some code about your custom geometry?

Comment: Please post your actual vertex data structure. WebGL implementations can be very strict about alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved!!

@GuyGood: you're right when you say that every vertex need a UV-Vector2, but it's wrong to say that geometry.faceVertexUvs.length should be equal to geometry.vertices.length...

it seems that facevertexUvs is a matrix, and not an array..well, it is an array of arrays..not properly a matrix..in fact I think it can be used to handle multi-mesh objects..if facevertexUvs.length == 3, we have 3 submeshes, so 3 arrays..each one of them has a length equal to the number of faces of a particular submesh..and every face knows the UV mapping about the 3 vertices defining that face..

hope this is clear and helpful!!